# How NOT to remove an environment variable in an MSI Installer during the uninstall?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, environment-variables, windows-installer

I created an MSI Installer with Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects. During the installation process the user specifies a path for an environment variable to the registry. My problem is that the installer removes it automatically during the uninstall process. How could I achieve that it will not be removed? (Because I need this environmental variable for other programs)

The folder that stores the variable:
[image]

The variable itself:

[image]

I tried to make a copy of the variable in the BeforeUninstall event and then in the AfterInstall event set the variable again. But it did not work because I still have the environmental variable in the afterInstall event and after the installer quits the variable is gone.

Comment: Assuming you're adding the registry entry via the "Registry" window that VS Installer Projects offers for such, then you can do this for a **key** but not for a **value**. An added key will have a "DeleteAtUninstall" property (shown in the "Properties" side-pane), which you can set to "False" (also the default). If you *need* a value, then add it as a sub-entry to a key, maybe.

Comment: ... I can post a fuller answer, if this is, in fact, what you're asking about.

Comment: @AdrianMole This would be what I asked about but my problem is that it is set to false and it still deletes the system environmental variable

Comment: To which component this registry belong to? Check component setting and set it to permanent attribute.

Comment: @VivekJaiswal Where can I find the component setting and its permanent attribute? You could also write a full answer.

Comment: the reason being not posting answer is because I'm not sure about generating installer using visual studio. however, i am well aware about MSI technology. You can edit the generated MSI using orca tool and traverse to component table. if you find the exact component, you can change the attribute column. The value of permamnet attribute is 16. So if it's present value is 0, you can use that or if integer is there, you could add that. And remember, all the  above steps(editing msi) could be easily automated.